# /etc/passwd.org, /etc/group.org, /etc/shadow.org files

Tags: debian, passwd, shadow

On a Debian 10 server, which started as Debian 7 and updated whenever new version came out, I accidentally found these three files:

`/etc/passwd.org`, `/etc/group.org`, `/etc/shadow.org`

The backup files `/etc/passwd-`, `/etc/group-`, `/etc/shadow-` and other *- files are present, as they should.

For example, all `passwd` files are (same applies for the other two):

```
$ ll /etc/passwd*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,1K Αυγ  13 14:08 /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,1K Αυγ  13 14:06 /etc/passwd-
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,0K Ιουν 20  2015 /etc/passwd.org
```

Their last access time is somewhere in 2015. Their contents are on par with `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, `/etc/shadow`, as they probably were some time in the past - I can see some deleted users. I cannot find any info of such *org files. Does anybody has any idea what are there *org files and what is their use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.org` files are remnants of an old [`base-passwd` upgrade](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/-/blob/b7a4fb63ea7f6267e9c0923d038d9e2a6147897a/debian/postinst#L93), which detected differences between the Debian default system accounts and those present on the system. When this happened, the upgrade would have offered to fix the files, keeping backups with `.org` suffixes.

They can be deleted now.